# How to create a custom 'fluid' layout in Display Suite

Tags: display-suite

I created a Display suite custom layout following this tutorial: https://drupal.org/node/1098068

It works fine, but I need this custom layout to be Fluid.

> In Display Suite, the "fluid" refers to the templates ability to
>   expand the column width if one (or more) columns are empty.

How can I do this? I guess I need to add some php code which will add some extras css classes. But I don't know how and where to add this code.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the custom layout in the *Manage Display* page:

[image]

And add the required CSS in your theme. See the examples included in Display Suite:

[image]